# Returning bytebuffer from jni is copy or reference?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I am returning the bytebuffer from jni to java layer.

```
    getData(JNIENV, *env, jobject obj ) {

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexA);


    while(dataAvailable == 0){
        pthread_cond_wait (&cond, &MutexA);
    }

    dataAvailable = 0;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&MutexA);

    return jnv->NewDirectByteBuffer(DataPointer, dataSize);
}
```

From Java :

```
  while (1) {
     ByteBuffer byteBuffer = getData();

  }
```

Does this byteBuffer is referenced to the DataPointer, or, does it copy to 'byteBuffer' variable in the java layer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Java guide NewDirectByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#new_direct_byte_buffer)

> Allocates and returns a direct java.nio.ByteBuffer referring to the
>   block of memory starting at the memory address address and extending
>   capacity bytes.
>
> Native code that calls this function and returns the resulting
>   byte-buffer object to Java-level code should ensure that the buffer
>   refers to a valid region of memory that is accessible for reading and,
>   if appropriate, writing. An attempt to access an invalid memory
>   location from Java code will either return an arbitrary value, have no
>   visible effect, or cause an unspecified exception to be thrown.

Comment: Yep, it returns reference to an ByteBuffer object which is pointing to `DataPointer` :)

Answer (score 0):

it is `referenced to the DataPointer`, not make a copy. so keep the memory range in native in the life of Java ByteBuffer.

Answer (score -1):

Of course, You can use `get(byte[] dst, int offset, int length)` get byte array from ByteBuffer.